# Limiting current without generating (MUCH) heat (efficient)

Tags: charging, current-limiting

I need to Limit my current without changing voltage.
I need this for a few things, one of them is protection against short circuit without damaging a fuse or generating heat if that short circuit is going to last a long time.
second one is charging a phone at 5v and 1A/0.5A. the reason is the Lithium battery I'm using is not rated for that much current draw.

I used a MOSFET, a sense resistor and a transistor to limit the current. it's cheap and works well! it's good for powering LEDs as they don't change resistance that much to burn the MOSFET or empty my battery fast.

but for my application it'll be incredibly inefficient! for example my 5000mah battery could be charged at 4A but I want to charge it at 1a or 0.5A.
or charging a Super Capactior as they have small internal resistance from alithium battery (that gives as much current as you need, but it might blow up!)

Anything I can do? The voltage has to stay the same or otherwise the device will not work

Comment: If you limit the current the voltage can't stay the same. That said, you probably want a DC/DC converter with current limiting.

Comment: Yes! But don't they generate a lot of heat? As I said, I want to charge a phone that requires 5v to recognize the charge! But I don't want to give it 2A that it draws. Similar to connecting it to a lower rated 500mah 5v adapter. or powering anything with a coincell battery as they can't even produce much current. So it won't waste anything

Comment: You can't both give it 5V and not give it the 2A that it draws at 5V.

Comment: A switching DC/DC converter can produce very little heat (compared to a linear one).

Comment: Whatever you tries,  Ohm's law applies.

Comment: You are a bit confused about various things. But I believe @WoutervanOoijen is correct that what you want is a DC-DC converter. There are basically two choices for reducing voltage. Linear regulator and DC-DC converter. The latter is much more efficient if the voltage reduction is large (or the current is large). Specifically, you are looking for a Buck Converter. Google it.

Comment: If you are trying to supply 5V from a lower voltage, then google Boost Converter instead of Buck Converter.

Comment: @JImDearden I always had a hard time understanding ohm's law. I mean I get it, but I don't understand certain things, for example, if resistor turns the dropped voltage into heat. why when I use a multimeter and measure the voltage between resistor it's still the same?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Am I supposed to Lower the "Voltage" with the switching power supply, or is it a different kind of switching dc dc converter? because my phone needs 5v as I said. I was thinking of throwsing some current into a inductor and then letting it release, or using a transformer, and let the inductor act like a coincell battery:?

Comment: Charge a small capacitor to 5v. Then apply it to your battery. You can then limit the total current to the battery by the cycle frequency.

Comment: I don't think you do get Ohm's law. Its the relationship between **voltage and current in a circuit.** i.e. the current is directly proportional to voltage. The constant of proportionality is **conductivity**. The inverse of conductivity is resistance i.e V*1/R = I  or V = IR. What **determines the size of the current** is the voltage and **the resistance (of the load).** What you are asking is how to (magically) change the load resistance so that you can get a smaller current **for the same (fixed) voltage.** - You can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you (probably) want is a switching DC/DC converter with a current limit. You want it primarily for the current limiting. What it will do is lower its output voltage to the voltage level where the connected device consumes the current you have set as limit. This will be less than 5V (because at 5V your device consumes 2A), but still high enough that your device consumes (from your example) 0.5A.

Don't try to built this yourself, google or search the websites of the usuall suspects (for instance mouser or digikey for quality, aliexpress for low-budget).

Comment: Why shouldn't I build this myself :? That sounds pretty simple to me now! I asked this because many chargers which output 1a or when I connect my phone to my PC it doesn't heat up and it only outputs 500ma without lowering the voltage. i could build a switching adjustable switching regulator with a Sense resistor connected to the output! or just use a chip designed for this purpose!

Comment: Also my switching mini step up (3v to 5v) only outs 0.9a max when connected to my single cell 25c 4200mah battery. so I thought it must be doing something :?